# If the sequence $a_n/b_n$ converges to $1$ with $a_n,b_n\not =0,$ show that the sequence $(a_n/b_n)^p$ converges to $1$ for $p\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

If the sequence $a_n/b_n$ converges to $1$ with $a_n,b_n\not =0,$  show that the sequence $(a_n/b_n)^p$ converges to $1$ for $p\in \mathbb{Z}.$

I thought about showing that splitting the values of $p$ in three cases $p=0,p>0$ and $p<0.$ If $p=0$ then $$\underbrace{(a_n/b_n)(a_n/b_n)(a_n/b_n)...(a_n/b_n)}_\text{p times }\to 1.$$ Since $a_n/b_n\not =0$ and $(a_n/b_n)\not \to0$ when $p<0$ we can say that $$\underbrace{\frac{1}{(a_n/b_n)}\frac{1}{(a_n/b_n)}...\frac{1}{(a_n/b_n)}}_\text{|p| times }\to 1.$$ Is this a rigorous enough argument?

Comment: I find it fine. If your teacher is strict with formality, you can use induction to avoid the ellipses.

Comment: With more rigor: for each $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, the function $x\to x^p$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $1$ and maps $x=1$ to $1$. Continuous functions bring converging sequences to converging sequences and you are done.